# Joint constraints in PhysX

Tags: c++, physics, physics-engine, nvidia

I'm trying to use PhysX for my physics engine.  I'd like to use spherical joints, but I'm having trouble with the constraints.  All of the examples that I've found refer to SDK v2.8.  I'd like to stick with v3.0.  Even the [PhysX support center](http://supportcenteronline.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=1949) uses deprecated APIs.  There's a tutorial at the [support center](http://supportcenteronline.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=1949) (Ch 4 - Grass) that I'm trying to imitate.  Converting that code to the current API has been problematic.  NxSphericalJointDesc is deprecated.  How do you specify equivalent constraints to those found in the tutorial?

There's another [post](http://forums.developer.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=6587&pid=20641&mode=threaded&start=#entry20641) that talks about a similar problem.